# Swift Command Line Writing to File causes Memory Crash

Tags: swift

I'm attempting to write a script that will read the contents of html files in a folder, scrub them, and then write the contents to a csv file for analysis in another program. The script works fine, so long as the html file count is low (less than 1,000 or so HTML files), however when the html file count surpasses that (in my case I have roughly 9,000 files to scrub), The program will crash. I believe the problem is that the section relating to writing to csv is wrong some how. The script runs through the html folder two times. The first time it does so to get all of the unique words. During this section the memory usage remains low and relatively constant. During the second for loop through the html folder is where the memory usage escalates to a crash and I don't know why. I would appreciate any suggestions.

```
    import Foundation

    let filemanager:FileManager = FileManager();
    let path2folder:String = "My Documents/web";
    let directory:String = NSHomeDirectory() + "/" + path2folder;
    let files1 = filemanager.enumerator(atPath: directory);
    let files2 = filemanager.enumerator(atPath: directory); //Because I loop twice through the folder
    var count = 0;
    var mime_count = 0;

    var bag_of_words:[String] = [""]
    var words_in_file:[String] = [""]
    var csv_array:[String] = [""]
    var file_array:[[String:Int]] = [[:]]

    func trimWhiteSpace(array: [String]) -> [String]{
        var trim: [String] = []
        for word in array{
            trim.append(word.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines))
        }
        return trim;
    }
    func deleteDuplicateWords(array: [String]) -> [String] {
        var found_words_set = Set<String>()
        var unique: [String] = []
        for word in array {
            if found_words_set.contains(word) {
                // Do not add a duplicate word.
            }
            else {
                // Add word to the unique array.
                found_words_set.insert(word)
                // ... Append the word.
                unique.append(word)
            }
        }
        return unique
    }
    func deleteFlaggedWords(array: [String]) -> [String] {
        var found_words_set = Set<String>()
        found_words_set.insert("")
        found_words_set.insert("|")
        //...

        var clean: [String] = []
        for word in array {
            if found_words_set.contains(word) {
                // Do not add a duplicate word.
            }
            else {
                // ... Append the word.
                clean.append(word)
            }
        }
        return clean
    }
    func deletePunctuation(array: [String]) -> [String]{
        var scrubbed: [String] = []

        for word in array {
            var scrubbed_word = word

            let first = word.characters.first!
            if(first == "." ||
                first == "," ||
                first == "!" ||
                first == "?" ||
                first == ":" ||
                first == ";" ||
                first == ")" ||
                first == "("){
                scrubbed_word.remove(at: scrubbed_word.startIndex)
            }
            if(first == "\"" ||
                first == "'"){
                 scrubbed_word.remove(at: scrubbed_word.startIndex)
                //scrubbed_word = scrubbed_word.remove(at: scrubbed_word.startIndex)
            }

            let last = word.characters.last!
            if(last == "." ||
                last == "," ||
                last == "!" ||
                last == "?" ||
                last == ":" ||
                last == ";" ||
                last == ")" ||
                last == "("){
                scrubbed_word = word.substring(to: word.index(before: word.endIndex))
            }
            if(last == "\"" ||
                last == "'"){
                scrubbed_word = word.substring(to: word.index(before: word.endIndex))
                //scrubbed_word = scrubbed_word.substring(to: scrubbed_word.index(before: scrubbed_word.endIndex))
            }
            scrubbed.append(scrubbed_word)

        }
        return scrubbed
    }
    func sortWordArray(array: [String]) -> [String]{
        var sorted_array:[String]

        sorted_array = array.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending     }
        return sorted_array
    }

    print("Processing...")

    /**
     * Loop through all of the files in the folder
     * To find the all of the words used in all of the file
     **/
    while let file = files1?.nextObject(){
        /**
         * if you find a file, pass the location of the file to the dir variable
         **/
        if var dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
            dir = dir.deletingLastPathComponent()
            var path_st = path2folder + "/" + String(describing: file)
            var path = dir.appendingPathComponent(path_st)

            //reading html file
            do {
                var html_file_contents = try String(contentsOf: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                count = count + 1;

                words_in_file = html_file_contents.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)

                words_in_file = trimWhiteSpace(array: words_in_file)

                words_in_file = deleteFlaggedWords(array: words_in_file)

                words_in_file = deletePunctuation(array: words_in_file)

                bag_of_words = bag_of_words + words_in_file
            }
            catch {
                /* error handling here */
            }
        }
    }

    //OK, HERE'S ALL THE UNIQUE 'WORDS' IN ALL HTML FILES
    bag_of_words = trimWhiteSpace(array: bag_of_words)
    bag_of_words = deleteDuplicateWords(array: bag_of_words)
    bag_of_words = deleteFlaggedWords(array: bag_of_words)
    bag_of_words = deletePunctuation(array: bag_of_words)
    bag_of_words = sortWordArray(array: bag_of_words)
    bag_of_words = deleteDuplicateWords(array: bag_of_words) //Just do once more

    /**
     * Now that you have the word count array
     * Write word count array to a csv file
     **/
    let csv_file_name = "data.csv"
    let csv_path = URL(fileURLWithPath:     NSHomeDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(csv_file_name)
    //Create the First line in the CSV
    var csv_text = ""
    for w in bag_of_words{
        csv_text = csv_text + "\(w),"
    }    
    csv_text = csv_text + "\n"

    do{
        try csv_text.write(to: csv_path, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    }
    catch{
        print("\(error)")
    }

    /**
     * Now create the 2-D Array that will track the word count
     * Of each file and populate it with the word counts
     **/
    count = 0
    mime_count = 0
    while let file = files2?.nextObject(){

        /**
         * if you find a file, pass the location of the file to the dir variable
         **/
        if var dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {

            dir = dir.deletingLastPathComponent()
            var path_st = path2folder + "/" + String(describing: file)
            var path = dir.appendingPathComponent(path_st)

            //reading html file
            do {
                var html_file_contents = try String(contentsOf: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                count = count + 1;

                words_in_file = html_file_contents.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)

                words_in_file = trimWhiteSpace(array: words_in_file)
                words_in_file = deleteFlaggedWords(array: words_in_file)
                words_in_file = deletePunctuation(array: words_in_file)

                var counts:[String:Int] = [:]

                //Zero Out Counts
                for (index, element) in bag_of_words.enumerated(){
                    counts[element] = 0
                }

                //COUNT WORDS FOR THIS FILE
                let bag_of_words_set = Set(bag_of_words)
                for (index, element) in words_in_file.enumerated(){
                    if(counts[element] != nil){
                        counts[element] = counts[element]! + 1
                    }
                }
                csv_text = ""
                do {
                    for c in counts{
                        csv_text = csv_text + "\(c.value),"
                    }
                    csv_text.remove(at: csv_text.index(before: csv_text.endIndex))
                    csv_text = csv_text + "\n"
                    let csv_data = csv_text.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
                    //I THINK THIS IS WHERE THE MEMORY IS GOING CRAZY
                    if(FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: csv_path.path)){
                        do{
                            let file_handle = try FileHandle(forUpdating: csv_path)
                            file_handle.seekToEndOfFile()
                            file_handle.write(csv_data)
                            file_handle.closeFile()
                        }
                        catch{
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch {/* error handling here */
                    print("\(error)")
                }
            }
            catch {
            /* error handling here */
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add some autorelease pools in just the right places.

Comment: "I don't know why" _Why_ don't you know why? You have wonderful debugging tools at your disposal! It is very easy to discover where the memory rises and why. Don't throw your code at us like spaghetti and ask us to figure it out for you: _you_ figure it out.

Comment: I will google autorelease pools. Thank you rmaddy.
I wish I knew how to use the debugging tools in Xcode. This is my first "real" program in swift. But thank you for the comment, Matt.

Comment: @rmaddy OH MY GOSH! YES. You hit the nail on the head. I think an autoreleasepool block around the second for loop has fixed it! I'm crying right now. The program is running & it's currently on the 1,000th html file out of 9,000. The memory usage is level at 1GB. Thank you for the spot on advice. With your help I was able to find this page [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html) in the Apple documentation and indeed it says I may need to use this because it's a command line app. THANK YOU SO MUCH!